# How can I rank exact matches higher in azure search

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

I have an index in azure search that consists of person data like firstname and lastname.

[image]

[image]
When I search for 3 letter lastnames with a query like

```
rau&searchFields=LastName

/indexes/customers-index/docs?api-version=2016-09-01&search=rau&searchFields=LastName
```

The name rau is found but it is quite far at the end.

```
{
"@odata.context": "myurl/indexes('customers-index')/$metadata#docs(ID,FirstName,LastName)",
"value": [
    {
        "@search.score": 8.729204,
        "ID": "someid",
        "FirstName": "xxx",
        "LastName": "Liebetrau"
    },
    {
        "@search.score": 8.729204,
        "ID": "someid",
        "FirstName": "xxx",
        "LastName": "Damerau"
    },
    {
        "@search.score": 8.729204,
        "ID": "someid",
        "FirstName": "xxx",
        "LastName": "Rau"
```

More to the top are names like "Liebetrau","Damerau".

Is there a way to have exact matches at the top?

**EDIT**

Querying the index definition using the RestApi

```
GET https://myproduct.search.windows.net/indexes('customers-index')?api-version=2015-02-28-Preview
```

returned for LastName

```
 "name": "LastName",
  "type": "Edm.String",
  "searchable": true,
  "filterable": true,
  "retrievable": true,
  "sortable": true,
  "facetable": true,
  "key": false,
  "indexAnalyzer": "prefix",
  "searchAnalyzer": "standard",
  "analyzer": null,
  "synonymMaps": []
```

**Edit 1**

The analyzer definition

```
      "scoringProfiles": [],
  "defaultScoringProfile": null,
  "corsOptions": null,
  "suggesters": [],
  "analyzers": [
    {
      "name": "prefix",
      "tokenizer": "standard",
      "tokenFilters": [
        "lowercase",
        "my_edgeNGram"
      ],
      "charFilters": []
    }
  ],
  "tokenizers": [],
  "tokenFilters": [
    {
      "name": "my_edgeNGram",
      "minGram": 2,
      "maxGram": 20,
      "side": "back"
    }
  ],
  "charFilters": []
```

**Edit 2**

At the end specifying a ScoringProfile that i use whene querying did the trick

```
   {
    "name": "person-index",  
    "fields": [

       {
      "name": "ID",
      "type": "Edm.String",
      "searchable": false,
      "filterable": true,
      "retrievable": true,
      "sortable": true,
      "facetable": true,
      "key": true,
      "indexAnalyzer": null,
      "searchAnalyzer": null,
      "analyzer": null

    }
    ,
    {
      "name": "LastName",
      "type": "Edm.String",
      "searchable": true,
      "filterable": true,
      "retrievable": true,
      "sortable": true,
      "facetable": true,
      "key": false,
      "analyzer":  "my_standard"

    },
     {
      "name": "PartialLastName",
      "type": "Edm.String",
      "searchable": true,
      "filterable": true,
      "retrievable": true,
      "sortable": true,
      "facetable": true,
      "key": false,
      "indexAnalyzer": "prefix",
      "searchAnalyzer": "standard",
      "analyzer": null

    }
    ],
    "analyzers":[
    {
      "name":"my_standard",
      "@odata.type":"#Microsoft.Azure.Search.CustomAnalyzer",
      "tokenizer":"standard_v2",
      "tokenFilters":[ "lowercase", "asciifolding" ]
    },
    {
      "name":"prefix",
      "@odata.type":"#Microsoft.Azure.Search.CustomAnalyzer",
      "tokenizer":"standard_v2",
      "tokenFilters":[ "lowercase", "my_edgeNGram" ]
    }
  ],
  "tokenFilters":[
    {
      "name":"my_edgeNGram",
      "@odata.type":"#Microsoft.Azure.Search.EdgeNGramTokenFilterV2",
      "minGram":2,
      "maxGram":20,
      "side": "back"
    }
  ],
  "scoringProfiles":[
  {
    "name":"exactFirst",
    "text":{
      "weights":{ "LastName":2, "PartialLastName":1 }     
    }
  }
]
}
```

Comment: Hi Mathias, I'm surprised names like "Liebetrau" match your query "rau" since it seems you're looking for the exact term, not a suffix. Do you apply a custom analyzer on the LastName field? Can you share your full request and the response you're getting?

Comment: You might be right. I did not create the index myself and I could not reproduce the behaviour with a new index.I guess thats bad luck or can I see the analyzer somewhere? When I look at the definition of the index in azure on the tab Analyzers there is no entry

Comment: You can see the analyzers when you look at the index definition using the REST API, GET <service url>/indexes/<index-name>?api-version=2016-09-01. If the standard analyzer is used on the LastName field I would not expect documents with a last name other than "Rau" to match.

Comment: You were right with the guess about the analyzer being in place. I am not shure if somebody realy defined it or if using a datasource when creating an index analyzer is used by default. This explains why all the LastName entries are returned, but I still need to find a way to have the item "Rau" at the top

Comment: Can you share the analyzer configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The analyzer "prefix" set on the LastName field produces the following terms for the name *Liebetrau* : `au, rau, trau, etrau, betrau, ebetrau, iebetrau, libetrau`. These are [edge ngrams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-gram) of length ranging from 2 to 20 starting from the back of the word, as defined in the *my_edgeNGram* token filter in your index definition. The analyzer will process other names in the same way. 
When you search for the name *rau*, it matches all names as they all end with those characters. That's why all documents in your result set have the same relevance score.

You can test your analyzer configurations using the [Analyze API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/test-analyzer).

To learn more about custom analyzers please go [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/custom-analyzers-in-azure-search) and [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/custom-analyzers-in-azure-search/).

Hope that helps

Comment: Thank you that makes it clear. Would there still be a way to have exact matches of the search term more at the top?

Comment: I saw now where the idea to use edge ngrams came from by watching the video https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Data-Exposed/Custom-Analyzers-Search-Analytics--Portal-Querying-in-Azure-Search . It looks like a good idea because it finds more entries. I guess I will have two fields where one is queried by the default analyzer and the second by the ngram. In the client I would combine the results with the default analyzer results at the top. Btw the videos you did for virtual academy are awesome!

Comment: I found your article that explains my exact problem where you added a scoring profile to rank exact matches higher. Nice. https://azure.microsoft.com/de-de/blog/custom-analyzers-in-azure-search/

Comment: Good to hear, let me know if I can help with anything else.